# Batch file word slot machine

Tags: batch-file

So I found this batch online and been trying to toy with it for awhile, I am very new into batch and tried to watch some tutorials but am getting no where. So what I am trying to do is make a word / label generator where it picks a semi random label. I want to make it like a lottery / slot machine thing where you have your normal prize, common prize, uncommon prize, rare, and super rare.

This is what I have so far

test.bat file

```
    @echo off

    set /a rnd=%random%%%10

    for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (list.txt) do if %rnd%==%%a  echo %%b

    pause
```

List.txt

```
1 Yellow_Star
2 Yellow_Star
3 Rare_Star
4 Yellow_Star
5 Uncommon_Star
6 Yellow_Star
7 Common_Star
8 Yellow_Star
9 Silver_Star
10 Yellow_Star
```

So I tried to do it in the list where yellow star is a higher chance but I want to avoid doing it like so and make it where Silver star is like a 1/100 chance of getting that Where yellow would be more of a 1/1 etc.

Comment: StackOverflow offers help and advice to those who report difficulties in running/fixing issues with their provided scripts/code. Without your script/code, and a clear explanation of the issues with it, _(you have neither)_, your question is off topic.

Comment: Oh I am sorry about that, I didn't know if someone could of helped me make on or pointed me into a direction that I couldn't find on google.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].  Consider generating a random number modulo 100, then test whether it is greater than or equal to the desired threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick "translation" of jwdonahues suggestion to batch code:

```
@echo off
setlocal 

:loop
set /a "prize=%random% %% 100 +1" & REM generates 1...100
REM echo prize=%prize%

if %prize% leq 100 set star=common
if %prize% leq 40 set star=yellow
if %prize% leq 20 set star=silver
if %prize% leq 10 set star=uncommon
if %prize% leq 1 set star=rare

echo You earned a %star% star!
pause
goto :loop
```

`if %prize% leq 100 set star=common` can be reduced to just `set star=common`, but I kept the long version for better understanding.

This gives you a 1% chace for a rare star, 9% (10-1) for an uncommon star, 10% (20-10) for a silver, 20% (40-20) for a yellow and a 60% (100-40) for a common star. Adjust the numbers to your needs.

(Note, just to prevent any "how random is %random%" arguments:  the numbers are not exactly evenly distributed, but you will need literally thousands of runs to even get an idea of that. And remember, even coins and dices do not provide even distribution)

Comment: Thank you so much, I never knew about leq and every thing I looked at on google never mentioned it either. Thanks again.

Comment: You may be interested in [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/). And remember: you can get help with every command, for example `if /?`

Answer (score 1):

You could use your existing code if you create a `List.txt` that has 100 entries in it.

1 entry is Silver_Star - (1 / 100)

10 entries are Yellow (10/100)

etc.

This is a "pragmatic brute force" approach :) just to highlight that there is more than one way to solve a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, yeah I was trying to avoid doing that haha, I thought about doing it that way, I just didn't know if there was a way to do something like set Silver_Star 1/100 etc. I am doing some research online to find something like that but it is a little different coding then I am use too.

Comment: @jwdonahue had a better idea - Add an incrementing percentage to your file and use a smaller than check.

Comment: How would I do that percentage thing? I looked at many help threads on here and other places and tried google with a batch file percent thing and I couldn't find anything?

Comment: I'm not going to edit my answer with an explanation because my code syntax will be wrong but the idea posed by @jwdonahue is that you generate a random number between 1 and 100 then you use the LEQ (less than or equal to) to lookup a value in your text file. instead of numbers 1 to 10 in your file you have first line = 10 (for 10%), next line could be 60 (=50% because its less than 60 but larger than 10), next line might be 90 (=30% because it's between 60 and 90). that's the general idea but I wouldn't be able to code it. Well.. couldn't be bothered learning such an awful language!